# Add up the column values in while loop if it comes repetedly

Tags: java, sum

I am creating a table from  ajax and the getting of values using a while loop:

```
while (rstdb.next()) {
        rstdb.getInt(1)+"~"+ rstdb.getInt(2);
}
```

In my while loop my  `rstdb.getInt(1)` will be **2,2,2,2,2,3,3......** and second values `rstdb.getInt(2)` are **10,20,30,40,50,10,20,.....**

I need to sum up the values specific to 2 and values specific to 3 seperate.

ie,

[image]

It means **10+20+30+40+50 =150 for  2**  and **10+20 =30 for 3**.

It may contain single values also for example it may have **4,5,5,6,7,7....**

How can I do that?

I need something like:

```
while (rstdb.next()) {
            rstdb.getInt(1)+"~"+ rstdb.getInt(2)+"~"+sum;
    }
```

The variable `sum` should contain the sum up value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use map for this. You can have a map which should be mapping the specific number with sum of it's corresponding value.

```
int c1, c2;
Map<Integer, Integer> sum = new HashMap<>();
while (rstdb.next()) {
    c1 = rstdb.getInt(1); 
    c2 = rstdb.getInt(2);
    if(sum.containsKey(c1)) {
        sum.put(c1, sum.get(c1) + c2);
       //               ^ will return current sum of second column
    } else {
        sum.put(c1, c2);
    }
    rstdb.getInt(1)+"~"+ rstdb.getInt(2)+"~"+sum.get(c1);
}
```

Comment: I need to add up `rstdb.getInt(2)` only.

Comment: What do you mean, I think that is what I am doing. I am only adding first column. Please look at code first.

Comment: afzalex the values need to be summed up is double and first coulmn values are are int. What change must do.?`sum.put(c1, sum.get(c1) + c2);`this means you are summing up first and last columns?? thats what I confused!!

Comment: 1. The values being summed up are int. 2. It is second column which is summed up. first column is only being used as key. You should try or inspect code carefully. @Santhucool

Answer (score 1):

You can use an integer to integer map:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> integerMap = new HashMap<>();

    while (rstdb.next()) {
        int column1 = rstdb.getInt(1);
        int column2 = rstdb.getInt(2);
        if (integerMap.containsKey(column1)) {
            int currentSum = integerMap.get(column1);
            integerMap.put(column1, currentSum + column2);
        } else {
            integerMap.put(column1, column2);
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** to print out the map, you can use loop through the entrySet of the map:

```
for (Map.Entry entry : integerMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println(entry.getKey() +  " : " + entry.getValue());
    }
```

Comment: I need to out.print the values once done with calculations. how to do that? What I am doing is as `outstring = outstring+rstdb.getInt(1)+"~"+ rstdb.getInt(2); ` then outside while loop `out.print(outstring )`. How I use your code to acheive it?